# MVC3 virtual directory view folder is very slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I have an MVC3 application which uses views and controllers as one would usually do.

I also have a controller `TestController` that returns views from a virtual directory setup in IIS 7.5.

Inside IIS under Views I've added the virtual directory `Test` which points to a directory on my local disk with my cshtml pages.

The rendering of the view takes up to 20 minutes on my first request, but subsequent requests take seconds.

The actual folder on my local machine contains 1000s of cshtml pages - would this be an issue?

Why would it take my application 20 minutes (first request) to render a view from a virtual directory and seconds to render a view in the solution itself?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**[Further Update] - This happened a number of times and then just stopped happening. I then had to remove the virtual directory and re-add it in IIS and it started happening again.**

I decided to run ants performance profiler. This is the result (I stopped it after almost 30 minutes of waiting)
[image: Ants performance profiler]

I have a feeling we may be seeing a deadlock, but I have no idea of how to test this

Comment: I don't know if this issue has anything related to IIS, but thousands of cshtml pages sounds like too much. what's the purpose of them? Is this such a large site? Probably missuse of the templating engine?

Answer (score 1):

After creating my own virtual path provider, I found that once a file was requested from my virtual directory, it iterates through every file in the directory and calls GetCacheDependency on every file.

I believe Pranav's explanation above is correct, and hence the answer, but below is the approach I've taken:

1. Moved my files from disk to couchbase
2. Create my own custom VirtualPathProvider
3. Create my own custom CacheDependency
4. If a file is a virtual file return my custom CacheDependecy, else
   use the default
5. Use MSMQ to invalidate a cache